# Creation order of ContentNote and ContentDocument

Tags: trigger, contentdocument, contentnote

When you create a new enhanced Note in the UI, it creates a ContentNote and a ContentDocument record.  Does anyone know the creation order of the records?  Client wants me to write a trigger for the enhanced Note, and triggers are allowed only for ContentDocument, not ContentNote.

Comment: ContentNote is related to ContentDocument via ContentDocumentLink (a junction). Triggers are available on ContentDocumentLink which will only exist once both of its parents exist (ContentNote, ContentDocumentLink)

Comment: Yes, but what is the order of creation?  Is the ContentNote created first or the ContentDocument?

Comment: why does it matter; until the `ContentDocumentLink` is inserted, you don't have a trigger point to attach code to; and by then, you have access to both the ContentNote and ContentDocument to do what you need to

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Disregard my ill-informed comment to your OP*

`ContentNote` is saved with key prefix `069` which is a `ContentDocument`. And, `ContentDocument` is the parent of `ContentVersion` (key prefix of `068`).

You can think of the `ContentDocument` as the header and ContentVersion as the actual "note" -- with multiple versions supported. As you edit the Note and click Save, a new `ContentVersion` is created - but under the same `ContentDocument`

Since `ContentNotes` are typically added as children to some Object (like `Account` or `Opportunity`), the relationship between the ContentNote (i.e. `ContentDocument`) and the Account or Opportunity is handled via a `ContentDocumentLink`.

So, what happens first when the Note is first saved?

1. `ContentVersion` is created (trigger possible)
2. `ContentDocument` is created (happens automatically when the first ContentVersion is saved). Trigger is also possible although it is not clear to me if you'll get control when this object is initially inserted via the side effect of #1
3. `ContentDocumentLink` is inserted - the link(junction) between the Account (or Opportunity or ...) and `ContentDocument` - trigger also possible

Answer (score 5):

FYI to anyone else struggling with this as I am, this is the trigger firing order when the "New" Content Note button is clicked:

```
ContentVersion BEFORE_INSERT
ContentDocument BEFORE_INSERT
ContentDocument AFTER_INSERT
ContentDocumentLink BEFORE_INSERT
ContentDocumentLink AFTER_INSERT
ContentDocument BEFORE_UPDATE
ContentDocument AFTER_UPDATE
ContentVersion AFTER_INSERT
ContentDocumentLink BEFORE_INSERT
ContentVersion BEFORE_UPDATE
ContentDocument BEFORE_UPDATE
ContentDocument AFTER_UPDATE
ContentVersion AFTER_UPDATE
ContentDocumentLink AFTER_INSERT
```

and when "Save" is clicked:

```
ContentVersion BEFORE_INSERT
ContentDocument BEFORE_UPDATE
ContentDocument AFTER_UPDATE
ContentVersion AFTER_INSERT
```

**PS**

Just found this detailed post [Triggers on ContentObjects](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177008/triggers-on-contentobjects).