# Triggers on ContentObjects

Tags: apex, trigger, standard-objects, files, chatter-file

We've been working with Attachment records on our custom objects, and we now need to migrate to Files (you know, that related list that shows up everywhere).
We have a lot of trigger logic on Attachment, and I need to get the exact same logic to work on Files (update fields of certain parent objects, prevent duplicates on some parent objects, prevent users from deleting other user's attachments/files...).
The problem is that the 3 relevant objects (`ContentVersion`, `ContentDocument` and `ContentDocumentLink`) are illogical, no single object has all the data I need or is triggered in a sane manner. To try and understand I put some trace flages (`System.debug()`) in the triggers, and I do not understand the results.

```
 if (trigger.isBefore){
  if (trigger.isUpdate){
    for (ContentVersion cv : trigger.new){
        System.debug('Content_Version_Trigger BEFORE UPDATE fired at: '+Datetime.now());
        System.debug(cv);
      }
  }
  else if (trigger.isInsert){
      for (ContentVersion cv : trigger.new){
        System.debug('Content_Version_Trigger BEFORE INSERT fired at: '+Datetime.now());
        System.debug(cv);
      }
  }
  else if (trigger.isDelete){
      for (ContentVersion cv : trigger.old){
        System.debug('Content_Version_Trigger BEFORE DELETE fired at: '+Datetime.now());
        System.debug(cv);
      }
  }
}
else if (trigger.isAfter){
  if (trigger.isUpdate){
    for (ContentVersion cv : trigger.new){
        System.debug('Content_Version_Trigger AFTER UPDATE fired at: '+Datetime.now());
        System.debug(cv);
      }
  }
  else if (trigger.isInsert){
      for (ContentVersion cv : trigger.new){
        System.debug('Content_Version_Trigger AFTER INSERT fired at: '+Datetime.now());
        System.debug(cv);
      }
  }
  else if (trigger.isDelete){
      for (ContentVersion cv : trigger.old){
        System.debug('Content_Version_Trigger AFTER DELETE fired at: '+Datetime.now());
        System.debug(cv);
      }
  }
}
```

The same code (with different objects, obviously) appears in the `ContentVersion`, `ContentDocument` and `ContentDocumentLink` triggers.

The relevant output is too large to post here.
[Debug log from inserting one file](https://paste.ofcode.org/mVp2tB7dJ9mvnR4M3LzmaM)
[Debug log from updating the description of one file](https://paste.ofcode.org/xFcuTwvzTPV6GRP7aru6nP)
It looks like the records are being created, modified and deleted in quick succession. Why?
What kind of effect will this have on my triggers? It seems as if I cannot reliably catch any single event, it's all or nothing. That of course, won't work, because I need different logic for different actions.
EDIT: I noticed that there was a bug in the trigger output. I fixed the trigger code and relinked the new output above. There are no deletes, but it looks like multiple `ContentDocumentLink`s are created, and the `ContentVersion` is updated accordingly.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Alright, I spent a couple of days going through it all, and the short answer is: it's complicated. Depending on what you want your triggers to do, you may need to have different triggers on different objects, `ContentVersion`, `ContentDocument` and `ContentDocumentLink`. Below find the long answer.

It turns out that the debug logs are different depending on whether you are using Salesforce Classic or Lightning Experience. Why? I don't know. (Third base!) Here is a brief summary of the chain of events when uploading (inserting), editing (changing the Description) and deleting a file.

```
Classic - INSERT:
    ContentVersion          before  insert - no ContentDocumentId
    ContentDocumentLink     before  insert - LinkEntity = current user
    ContentDocumentLink     after   insert - has Id
    ContentVersion          after   insert - has Id, ContentDocumentId
    ContentDocumentLink     before  insert - LinkEntity = object
    ContentVersion          before  update - Publish status changed from R to P
    ContentVersion          after   update - 
    ContentDocumentLink     after   insert - has Id
    
Classic - UPDATE:
    ContentVersion          before  update
    ContentDocument         before  update
    ContentVersion          after   update
    ContentDocument         after   update
    
Classic - DELETE:
    ContentDocument         before  delete
    ContentDocument         after   delete
    
LX - INSERT:
    ContentVersion          before  insert - no ContentDocumentId
    ContentDocument         before  insert
    ContentDocument         after   insert
    ContentDocumentLink     before  insert - LinkEntity = current user
    ContentDocumentLink     before  insert - LinkEntity = object
    ContentDocumentLink     after   insert - LinkEntity = current user
    ContentDocumentLink     after   insert - LinkEntity = object
    ContentDocument         before  update - Publish status changed from U to P
    ContentDocument         after   update
    ContentVersion          after   insert
    
LX - UPDATE:
    ContentVersion          before  update
    ContentDocument         before  update
    ContentDocument         after   update
    ContentVersion          after   update
    
LX - DELETE:
    ContentDocument         before  delete
    ContentDocument         after   delete
```

It immediately becomes obvious that for some reason the Classic logs don't have `insert` events on `ContentDocument`, and that's part of what threw me off. The other part is that for some reason, for a couple of days, uploading a file and attaching it to a record were 2 discrete steps in LX. Now it is back to being 1 step, I don't know what changed. (I'm still looking into that and will update this answer if I ever find out).

The next most obvious conclusion is that if I want my triggers to have any effect on the parent record of the file, then I need to capture the `before insert` trigger on `ContentDocumentLink`.
If I want to capture edit events of the actual file then I need to capture the `before update` trigger on `ContentVersion`.
And if I want to capture `before` or `after` `delete` events, then I need to capture them on the `ContentDocument` trigger.

I use trigger handler classes for all my objects (one for each object), so in this case I created a single handler class for all 3 objects, and then the various triggers call the correct function from the correct event.

A final note: it's very important to make sure that the record(s) you have captured in the trigger are the ones you want to work on, since multiple `insert` or `update` events can happen in a single transaction, to the same record, but not necessarily when you want it to. For example, the `before insert` on `ContentDocumentLink`. Sometimes the `LinkedEntity` is the user, and sometimes the record you want to edit. So make doubly certain!

Comment: Thanks very much for your sharing. It saved me a lot of time to figure it out myself.