# Prevent creating new file while uploading new file from Salesforce standard upload button

Tags: apex, trigger, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

Whenever a user uploads a new file under a particular record, I need to check for an existing file with the same name. If there is an existing file, then it should not create a new document; instead of that it should update the existing file.

For this requirement, on which object do I need to write a trigger?

To prevent creating a new record, I need to prevent creating a new ContentDocument. The problem I am facing is not being able to get the parent id from ContentDocument and ContentVersion object.

**Update:**

```
trigger ContentVersionTrigger on ContentVersion(after insert) {
    /* here i have some logic to get the cusReportList 
       fileName have the uploaded file names
    */
    Map<Id,Customer_Report__c> cusReportList = new Map<Id,Customer_Report__c>(
      [SELECT Id,Name FROM Customer_Report__c 
       WHERE Atlas_Account_Id__c  IN : atlasAccountIds]);
    system.debug('cusReportList '+cusReportList);
    if(cusReportList.size() > 0){
        List<String> docToDelete = new List<String>();
        Set<String> docIds = new Set<String>();
        Set<String> fileNameWithId = new Set<String>();
        System.debug(cusReportList.keyset() );
        System.debug('fileName '+fileName);
        List<ContentDocumentLink> existing = 
               [SELECT Id,ContentDocumentId,LinkedEntityId,ContentDocument.Title
                                 FROM ContentDocumentLink 
                                 WHERE LinkedEntityId IN : cusReportList.keyset() 
                                   AND ContentDocument.Title IN :fileName];
        for(ContentDocumentLink cdi : existing){
            if(!fileNameWithId.contains(cdi.ContentDocument.Title+cdi.LinkedEntityId)){
                fileNameWithId.add(cdi.ContentDocument.Title+cdi.LinkedEntityId);
            } else {
                docToDelete.add(cdi.ContentDocumentId);
            }
        }
        if(docToDelete.size() > 0){
            List<ContentDocument> conDocToDelete = [SELECT Id from ContentDocument WHERE Id IN :docToDelete];
            if(conDocToDelete.size() > 0){
                try{
                    delete conDocToDelete;
                } catch (Exception e){
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please show what you have tried - use [edit]

Comment: @cropredy Update my question with code

Comment: you can't prevent creating a new ContentDocument - you can only clean it up (delete it) later.  Not sure why you care about ContentDocument.ParentId which points at a content library. You are also eating your delete exception which is not good practice.

Comment: @cropredy Can you please provide me a sample code? My requirement is whenever a user uploads a file with the same name it should create a new content version in the existing content document. it should not create new content document.

Comment: @cropredy Added some suggestions for improving or reducing the code. The question remains: What is the purpose of ContentDocument.ParentId in your use case? If you can provide details on that, it will he easy to provide a reply.

Comment: this is a complex problem that I don't have time to work through now (sorry). This [post is of some help](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177008/triggers-on-contentobjects).  My inclination would be detect matches in ContentVersion after insert and then delegate the cloning/deletion to an async (future or queueable)