# Why is this ContentNote trigger receiving 1 record at a time even though multiple records are being inserted?

Tags: trigger, bulkification, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink, contentnote

I am seeing a `ContentNote` trigger called on individual rows even though a bulk insert is done. A stripped down version follows.

The debug log output demonstrates that 3 `ContentNote` objects are inserted in one DML operation. But I do not understand why the triggers appear to be called *3 times for 1 record each time* rather than *1 times for 3 records*. It as if this object has some **non-bulkified logic behind the scenes**. Or I am doing something crazy here?

(Some context: [Creation order of ContentNote and ContentDocument](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137227/creation-order-of-contentnote-and-contentdocument) and [Triggers on ContentObjects](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177008/triggers-on-contentobjects).)

Test:

```
@IsTest
static void contentNoteTrigger() {
    SObject[] cns = new SObject[] {};
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // This property is set to ContentNote.SObjectType
        SObject cn = ContentNotes.noteType.newSObject();
        cn.put('Title', 'T' + i);
        cn.put('Content', Blob.valueOf('B' + i));
        cns.add(cn);
    }
    insert cns;
}
```

Triggers:

```
trigger ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument (
        before insert,
        before update,
        before delete,
        after insert,
        after update,
        after delete
        ) {
    cve.Notes.handle(
            Trigger.operationType,
            Trigger.old,
            Trigger.new,
            Trigger.oldMap,
            Trigger.newMap
            );
}

trigger ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentLinkDocument (
        before insert,
        before update,
        before delete,
        after insert,
        after update,
        after delete
        ) {
    cve.Notes.handle(
            Trigger.operationType,
            Trigger.old,
            Trigger.new,
            Trigger.oldMap,
            Trigger.newMap
            );
}
```

Handler:

```
public class Notes {
    public static void handle(
            TriggerOperation operation,
            SObject[] oldList,
            SObject[] newList,
            Map<Id, SObject> oldMap,
            Map<Id, SObject> newMap) {

        System.debug('>>>'
                + ' operation ' + operation
                + ' oldList ' + (oldList != null ? oldList.size() : 0)
                + ' oldType ' + (oldList != null ? String.valueOf(oldList[0].getSobjectType()) : 'unknown')
                + ' newList ' + (newList != null ? newList.size() : 0)
                + ' newType ' + (newList != null ? String.valueOf(newList[0].getSobjectType()) : 'unknown')
        );
    }
}
```

Debug output (with cumulative usage blocks stripped out for brevity):

```
43.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;NBA,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
12:38:57.1 (1416302)|EXECUTION_STARTED
12:38:57.1 (1452174)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01pf0000000x1D6|cve.NoteMigrationBatchableTest.contentNoteTrigger()
12:38:57.1 (16501439)|DML_BEGIN|[610]|Op:Insert|Type:SObject|Rows:3
12:38:57.1 (28098355)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qf00000005HML|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event BeforeInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (31360662)|USER_DEBUG|[357]|DEBUG|>>> operation BEFORE_INSERT oldList 0 oldType unknown newList 1 newType ContentDocument
12:38:57.1 (32242368)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event BeforeInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (54280142)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qf00000005HML|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event AfterInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (54651926)|USER_DEBUG|[357]|DEBUG|>>> operation AFTER_INSERT oldList 0 oldType unknown newList 1 newType ContentDocument
12:38:57.1 (55351761)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event AfterInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (71518588)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qf00000005HML|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event BeforeInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (71812326)|USER_DEBUG|[357]|DEBUG|>>> operation BEFORE_INSERT oldList 0 oldType unknown newList 1 newType ContentDocument
12:38:57.1 (72515949)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event BeforeInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (77836899)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qf00000005HML|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event AfterInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (78075518)|USER_DEBUG|[357]|DEBUG|>>> operation AFTER_INSERT oldList 0 oldType unknown newList 1 newType ContentDocument
12:38:57.1 (78753802)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event AfterInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (85166445)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qf00000005HML|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event BeforeInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (85381693)|USER_DEBUG|[357]|DEBUG|>>> operation BEFORE_INSERT oldList 0 oldType unknown newList 1 newType ContentDocument
12:38:57.1 (86065895)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event BeforeInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (90693473)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qf00000005HML|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event AfterInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (90957612)|USER_DEBUG|[357]|DEBUG|>>> operation AFTER_INSERT oldList 0 oldType unknown newList 1 newType ContentDocument
12:38:57.1 (91653020)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event AfterInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (149520994)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qf00000005HMQ|cve.ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink trigger event BeforeInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentLinkTrigger
12:38:57.1 (150013102)|USER_DEBUG|[357]|DEBUG|>>> operation BEFORE_INSERT oldList 0 oldType unknown newList 1 newType ContentDocumentLink
12:38:57.1 (150726889)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|cve.ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink trigger event BeforeInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentLinkTrigger
12:38:57.1 (223089987)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qf00000005HMQ|cve.ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink trigger event AfterInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentLinkTrigger
12:38:57.1 (223448677)|USER_DEBUG|[357]|DEBUG|>>> operation AFTER_INSERT oldList 0 oldType unknown newList 1 newType ContentDocumentLink
12:38:57.1 (224168615)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|cve.ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink trigger event AfterInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentLinkTrigger
12:38:57.1 (236219488)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qf00000005HML|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event BeforeUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (236538455)|USER_DEBUG|[357]|DEBUG|>>> operation BEFORE_UPDATE oldList 1 oldType ContentDocument newList 1 newType ContentDocument
12:38:57.1 (237229932)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event BeforeUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (243689004)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qf00000005HML|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event AfterUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (243983648)|USER_DEBUG|[357]|DEBUG|>>> operation AFTER_UPDATE oldList 1 oldType ContentDocument newList 1 newType ContentDocument
12:38:57.1 (244778403)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event AfterUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (257443558)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qf00000005HMQ|cve.ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink trigger event BeforeInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentLinkTrigger
12:38:57.1 (257708522)|USER_DEBUG|[357]|DEBUG|>>> operation BEFORE_INSERT oldList 0 oldType unknown newList 1 newType ContentDocumentLink
12:38:57.1 (258391299)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|cve.ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink trigger event BeforeInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentLinkTrigger
12:38:57.1 (290942926)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qf00000005HMQ|cve.ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink trigger event AfterInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentLinkTrigger
12:38:57.1 (291266435)|USER_DEBUG|[357]|DEBUG|>>> operation AFTER_INSERT oldList 0 oldType unknown newList 1 newType ContentDocumentLink
12:38:57.1 (292266397)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|cve.ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink trigger event AfterInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentLinkTrigger
12:38:57.1 (321547177)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qf00000005HML|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event BeforeUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (321927536)|USER_DEBUG|[357]|DEBUG|>>> operation BEFORE_UPDATE oldList 1 oldType ContentDocument newList 1 newType ContentDocument
12:38:57.1 (322868304)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event BeforeUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (328440445)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qf00000005HML|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event AfterUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (328875032)|USER_DEBUG|[357]|DEBUG|>>> operation AFTER_UPDATE oldList 1 oldType ContentDocument newList 1 newType ContentDocument
12:38:57.1 (329862766)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event AfterUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (341966647)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qf00000005HMQ|cve.ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink trigger event BeforeInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentLinkTrigger
12:38:57.1 (342282022)|USER_DEBUG|[357]|DEBUG|>>> operation BEFORE_INSERT oldList 0 oldType unknown newList 1 newType ContentDocumentLink
12:38:57.1 (343016551)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|cve.ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink trigger event BeforeInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentLinkTrigger
12:38:57.1 (369675752)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qf00000005HMQ|cve.ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink trigger event AfterInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentLinkTrigger
12:38:57.1 (370019273)|USER_DEBUG|[357]|DEBUG|>>> operation AFTER_INSERT oldList 0 oldType unknown newList 1 newType ContentDocumentLink
12:38:57.1 (370754442)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|cve.ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink trigger event AfterInsert|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentLinkTrigger
12:38:57.1 (380178743)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qf00000005HML|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event BeforeUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (380497937)|USER_DEBUG|[357]|DEBUG|>>> operation BEFORE_UPDATE oldList 1 oldType ContentDocument newList 1 newType ContentDocument
12:38:57.1 (381197363)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event BeforeUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (385991302)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qf00000005HML|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event AfterUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (386509529)|USER_DEBUG|[357]|DEBUG|>>> operation AFTER_UPDATE oldList 1 oldType ContentDocument newList 1 newType ContentDocument
12:38:57.1 (387374558)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|cve.ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument trigger event AfterUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/cve/ContentDocumentTrigger
12:38:57.1 (415888379)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|cve.NoteMigrationBatchableTest.contentNoteTrigger()
12:38:57.1 (416735350)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a Salesforce Case on this and that was handled promptly and effectively.

Unfortunately the answer was that the current implementation supports the "one at a time" situation that arises from the user interface but does not support the "bulk" case as the ContentDocument objects are created one at a time from the ContentNote objects.