# Workaround for the one record at a time trigger invocation when starting from Content Note

Tags: trigger, bulkification, contentdocument, contentnote

I hit this platform problem a while ago [Why is this ContentNote trigger receiving 1 record at a time even though multiple records are being inserted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/228887/why-is-this-contentnote-trigger-receiving-1-record-at-a-time-even-though-multipl). But today I've hit it again and now I need a workaround.

It appears that `ContentNote` is a facade over the [ContentObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_content.htm). I am directly inserting `ContentNote` objects. Does working with the underlying Content Objects instead (e.g. `ContentVersion`) avoid the trigger problem? Or is there some other way to get triggers called in bulk for `ContentNote`?

(I'd like to stay with the trigger approach as customers are used to the synchronous behavior with (older) Notes and it would be good to get the Enhanced Notes behaving in the same way.)

Some context: a trigger is used to enforce editing rights (and generate some custom event records) and we have some deep clone logic that can result in many notes being copied at once. Querying and DML is needed in the trigger, so when that logic is invoked one record at a time for many records, governor limits are hit.

Comment: Could you add some context on why you want to do so?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Sure, I’ve added a context paragraph at the end of the question.

Comment: What I'm saying is, why is it a problem? It's hard to know what a good workaround would be without knowing more specifically what you are working around. Would it work to shift some of the logic into async? A `Schedulable` job seems like it may well work for your needs.

Comment: @AdrianLarson The work being done is to support the same functionality for Content (Enhanced) Notes that has been in our product for 5 years for (original) Notes. For the latter, triggers behave as you would expect: a bulk insert results in a bulk call to the trigger. For the former, triggers behave in a surprising way: a bulk insert results in many calls to the trigger with a single record for each call. Given that Salesforce support pretty much said "that's the way it is", I'm wondering if there is a workaround where triggers ancontinue to be used. I'll make that clearer in the question.

Comment: Can you use static caching for your queries? It's hard to know if that's a good recommendation, but with a small enough table you might be able to just lazy load all the data you might need. Or you could move the logic to an async framework. It could be a complicated undertaking though.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thanks. Some caching could workaround this for this deep clone case. But a trigger solution would have the benefit of working for all cases e.g. bulk data upload if there is a pattern that works. If I don't get an answer here, I'll probably end up spending half a day going through alternatives like inserting ContentVersion directly. Would be great to save that time by knowing up front if there is a trigger solution or not.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Your comments have got me thinking about the caching approach and I think that is the pragmatic fix for the present deep clone case. The problem will probably come up again in the future in some other context...

Comment: Just to add this is same behaviour you have when you try to deploy content asset in bulk via Metadata API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer only relates to workarounds where the calling code can be modified: it is not a general solution to the question. It would be great if there was a pattern that caused the platform to behave in the normal pattern of bulk calling a trigger.

Thanks to Adrian's comments, I realized that my problem of:

- bulk update in controller
- platform layers convert into multiple single records calls to trigger
- my (already bulkified) trigger does queries for every single record call (as it is only passed a record at a time) and so hits governor limits

could be solved by leveraging the already present bulkification of the trigger:

- turn triggers off (through a pre-existing static boolean) in controller
- bulk update in the controller
- directly call the trigger's (already bulkified) handler class from controller passing the records in bulk

which has meant no refactoring necessary for the trigger/handler and instead this small change to the controller:

```
Triggers.areDisabled = true;               // Added code
SObject[] newNotes = new SObject [] {};
...
insert newNotes;
Notes.handle(                              // Added code
    TriggerOperation.AFTER_INSERT,
    null,
    newNotes,
    null,
    new Map<Id, SObject>(newNotes)
);
Trigger.areDisabled = false;               // Added code
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion (if your data volume is low enough) is to leverage lazy loading and cache all the records you could possibly need. There are obviously a variety of mechanisms to do so. For example we often whip up a specific `ProfileCache`, `RecordTypeCache`, etc. Below is a very simple example of the multitude of options available.

```
public with sharing class ProfileCache
{
    public Profile get(Id profileId)
    {
        if (records == null)
        {
            records = new Map<Id, Profile>([SELECT Name FROM Profile]);
        }
        return records.get(profileId);
    }
    static Map<Id, Profile> records;
}
```